# Angular resource get request is been canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a small angulaerjs app that uses angularjs resource in one of it's controllers. Here is the code for resource usage

```
  $scope.getFilteredTasks = function (filter) {

        var resource = $resource('{0}/api/orderTasks/filterTasks'.format($scope.baseUrl), { status: '@status', type: '@type', createdDate: '@createdDate', agentType: '@agentType', page: '@page', pageSize: '@pageSize' }, {
            'response': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
        });

        $('#loading').show();
        resource.response({
            status: filter.status,
            type: filter.type,
            createdDate: filter.createdDate,
            agentType: filter.agentType,
            page: $scope.currentPage,
            pageSize: $scope.pageSize
        },
            function (result) {
                $scope.resultTasks = result.Items;
                if ($scope.totalItems != result.TotalCount)
                    $scope.totalItems = result.TotalCount;
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            function (result) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                alert('Error in request!')
            });
    };
```

When the page first load everything is fine and i get all data that i need. But when I make second request (for example push the button on page that calls *getFilteredTask(filter)* function). I've got an result.status = -1. According to Fiddler and Chrome Network tab in dev tools request has status 200 but was cancelled. I've also checked the backend and found no problems, request was succsessfully handled and server returned all data that I need but I get cannceled request on client side.

**UPDATE**

It loooks like this problem appears only in Chrome. In IE 11 for example everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

the issue might be that you were making the ajax request from a link, and not preventing the link from being followed. So if you are doing this in an `onclick` attribute, make sure to `return false;` as well.